# Why does my roommate's cat like me so much?

Tags: cats, behavior

I started renting a room from someone around 6 months ago. My roommate informed me at the time that she had a cat but that it didn't like anyone but her. It hated any roommates she's had in the past. That's fine. I like cats but hey, you can't win em all.

Well this cat loves me. She's generally waiting for me when I get up in the morning, when I get home from the gym, and when I get home from work. She runs up to me and meows and I'll pet her for a few minutes. She follows me around the house and meows at my door when it's closed. If I get up in the middle of the night for water I'll hear her run up the stairs and meow at me in the dark. If I'm sitting on the couch to watch TV she'll sit next to me or sometimes on my lap which apparently she does for no one else, even my roommate. She'll even let me pick her up and carry her around.

So why does this cat like me? My roommate is the one who lavishes her in attention, feeds her, and changes her litter. My interactions are limited to a handful of minutes when I come in the door.

(if it makes a difference, the cat is female, I'm male, and my roommate is female)

Comment: Hooman! Thou shall not question thy overlord's actions but stand ready for belly rubs! ... Maybe you're just filling the gaps, like the owner wanting the cat to sleep at night rather than starting petting.

Comment: many people have asked themselves this question,why do this cat love me and only the cat have the answer to this.resistance is futile so just relax and enjoy the feeling of beeing unconditionally loved by a cat,there probably is an answer but i do not have it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

She may find that your personality fits hers more than her owners. Maybe the cat is overwhelmed by the attention her owner is giving her. You could encourage the owner to be less aggressively affectionate towards the cat.

Was the cat adopted as an older cat? You could remind them of their previous owner.

Answer (score 0):

It may just be that you are a friendly visitor, as with a kid being excited to see a favorite grandparent or uncle or whatever. Doesn't mean they like their own human any less, just that you are something fun and different. You make a fuss over them; why shouldn't they make a fuss over you?